# Expected an identifier - C

Tags: c

I am newbie in C and programming so I was trying the function Strrev() but I use a VM running linux and I realize the function is not available in linux so I found an alternative implementations available but I still having problem in my StrrevFunction when I compiler all the code.

**Main:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "strrevFunction.h"

int main()
{   
  char string1[30];

  printf("Escribe una frase\n");
gets(string1);

strrev(string1);

printf("Tu frase al reves es: %s\n", string1);

return 0;
}
```

**strrevFunction.c:**

```
#include "strrevFunction.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *strrev(char *str)
{
  char *p1, *p2;

  if (! str || ! *str)
        return str;
  for (p1 = str, p2 = str + strlen(str) - 1; p2 > p1; ++p1, --p2)
  {
        *p1 ^= *p2;
        *p2 ^= *p1;
        *p1 ^= *p2;
  }
  return str;
 };
```

**strrevFunction.h:**

```
#if !defined(strrev)
#define strrev

char *strrev(char *str);

#endif // MACRO
```

[OUTPUT ERRORS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9l4Fa.png)

[PROBLEMS: 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfZy2.png)

Comment: General advice: **never use `gets`**

Comment: Please, do not post text as pictures. Copy the output from the console and apste it in your post inside a code block, like you did for your code.

Comment: Anyway the problem with your code is that you mix up the preprocessing and compiling steps in the compilations: you define `strrev` as an empty macro, so once the preprocessor has run all the compiler sees for the following declaration of `strrev` is `char *(char *str);`

Comment: In other words, you cannot have the same symbol as both a macro and a normal identifier.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, if `gets` is so bad, why no standard has banned it from the standard library yet?  Just discourage it's use, but you had better to learn it, as you can find it in legacy code and probably you have to cope with its drawbacks (and probably you can have a totally controlled environment in which you know beforehand that you are never going to buffer overrun the pointers involved)  Anyway, please indicate some reasons for your assertion (which is correct, but fairly lacking rationale)

Comment: @LuisColorado can you help me I still having this error after uses fget() instead

Comment: The error has been indicated in the _accepted_ answer.  You need to select a different name for the `strrev` macro in your header file.  Just follow the instructions there.

Comment: @LuisColorado "_why no standard has banned it from the standard library yet?_" - `gets` was deprecated 22 years ago (back in C99) and removed in C11. There's no need to have to cope with its drawbacks. Never add it in new code and replace it whenever you see it in old code.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, I don't do it.... don't blame me.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, sorry then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The preprocessor

Given this code:

```
#if !defined(strrev)
#define strrev
char *strrev(char *str);
#endif
```

The preprocessor will expand that to the following invalid code

```
char * (char *str);
```

#### You appear to try to be using header guards

Use a more unique string for your header guard. Something like `MY_PROJECT_STRREVFUNCTION_H`

```
#if !defined(MY_PROJECT_STRREVFUNCTION_H)
#define MY_PROJECT_STRREVFUNCTION_H

char *strrev(char *str);

#endif
```